# Operaciones de lectura en firebase

Tags: javascript

estoy desarrollando una app con react-native y tengo una duda con respecto a las operaciones de lectura solicitadas a firebase ... en un momento dado consulto las solicitudes realizadas y me da el resultado de lecturas hasta ese momento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego vuelvo a consultar esto (sin ninguna acción explícitamente desde la aplicación)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me llama atención que haya aumentado el número de lecturas siendo que la aplicación se mantuvo en una pantalla donde no se realizaron solicitudes ni operaciones de lectura, alguien sabe por que puede ser esto ??

Answer (score 0):

Estos podrían ser algunos motivos:

- Las métricas no se muestran en tiempo real
- Una única consulta que devuelve 10 archivos contará como 10 operaciones lectura
- Las consultas en la consola también cuentan como reads

Y como recomendación, intenta evitar el uso de offsets siempre que te sea posible, pues si usas en la consulta un offset de 10 y esta te devuelve 1 resultado, te contará como 11 lecturas.

Comment: en realidad consulto una colección que contiene mas o menos 8 documentos, eso contaría como 8 consultas ?

Comment: Sí, así es como funciona.